# Xampp Apache is not starting SSL configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

```
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591528 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] AH02578: Init: Unable to read pass phrase [Hint: key introduced or changed before restart?]
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591679 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591698 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591711 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591724 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=RSA)
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591739 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591751 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591764 2015] [ssl:error] [pid 24469] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591780 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24469] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /opt/lampp/logs/error_log for more information
[Wed Mar 25 20:33:20.591790 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 24469] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key abc.domain.com:443:0, check /opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/domain.key
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello I had a similar problem... I solved it by not using any passphrase when generating the self signed certificate.

Comment: You have the command for generating .key file without passpharase thanks

Comment: openssl rsa -in www.key -out new.key

Answer (score 2):

You can create new key without passphrase:

```
openssl rsa -in www.key -out new.key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this using `SSLPassPhraseDialog`

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog  exec:/etc/httpd/conf/pwf.sh
```

pwf.sh file contents

```
#!/bin/sh
echo password
```